# Download 'Liked' tracks from Soundcloud using API

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I have PHP on my local web server and I would like to download all the 'Liked' tracks on my Soundcloud account (where a download is available).

I have created my App in Soundcloud (have the client id & secret key), have viewed the [Reference](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) but now no longer sure what to do to begin downloading the tracks. All my attempts so far have failed.

Can someone explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tracks which are marked as downloadable by their owner, you can just send a [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request using the `download_url` you get in the track representation. This will look something like `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/12345/download`.

For tracks which the owner has marked as non-downloadable, this isn't allowed by the [terms of use](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#caching).

Comment: Thanks, NickF :) Yep, I would purely be downloading those which have a value in the 'download_url' field. Do you have much experience of this? I tried (unsuccessfully) to run some scripts from the docs they provided - couldn't even get passed PHPUnit :'( Any help would be greatly appreciated :-D

Comment: The docs for PHP curl are here: http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php, or you could just use `file_get_contents`, or even just on the command line, it's as simple as `curl http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/94946557/download\?client_id\=YOUR_CLIENT_ID -L > blah.m4a`